# cmake find_program command does not find lib.exe

Tags: cmake

In my CMake file I need to use lib.exe in custom command when building on Windows to combine multiple static libraries into one. 
I tried to use `find_program` command to find the executable:

```
find_program(LIB_EXE NAMES lib.exe)
```

but it always sets the variable to not found. What is the right way to find lib.exe?

[EDIT] Fixed NAME->NAMES, but the program is still not found

Comment: Is `lib.exe` is located under a directory, specified in the `PATH` environment variable? What is output of `message("PATH: $ENV{PATH}")` (placed before the `find_program` call), and which directory contains `lib.exe`?

Comment: @Tsyvarev lib.exe is not located in a directory under path, but it is in the same directory as link.exe (${CMAKE_LINKER}), so cmake should be able to find it:
Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\Hostx64\x64

Comment: It is possible that `CMAKE_LINKER` is detected **not** by the means of `find_program` or so. (E.g., it could be taken from the registry, or requested from `MSBuild.exe` program which is used in Visual Studio). So you need to hint CMake with a directory to search. You may use [get_filename_component(DIRECTORY)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/get_filename_component.html) for extract directory part of the `CMAKE_LINKER` variable, and use that directory as a hint for `find_program`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you, this is probably the best way to go. Not sure how future-proof this method is, but this should work

Answer (score 2):

The proper keyword is  NAMES which may be omitted. Try adding the S or removing the keyword entirely.

I think you're  actually searching for the program `NAME`

Comment: You are right, I misread the documentation (I will update the question). But unfortunately find_program(LIB_EXE lib.exe) and well as find_program(LIB_EXE lib) and find_program(LIB_EXE NAMES lib.exe) gives not_found as well

Comment: It sounds like  you'll have to add a HINTS or PATHS clause.

Comment: Yeah, but which paths exactly. The program is a system utility and should be found by CMake I guess. In fact, the custom command works fine if I use lib.exe directly. Not sure if this is the best way though.

Comment: Check the CMakeCache.txt in your build folder. CMake may already  be finding it. I don't have a Windows machine available at the moment, but on my Linux machine all the linking tools are located. This gives a CMAKE_* style variable that you could use instead.

Comment: There is CMAKE_LINKER variable which points to link.exe, but I need lib.exe

Answer (score 0):

Check the file CMakeCache.txt in your build directory, and search for "lib.exe".

There you can find "lib.exe" can be located by the variable `${CMAKE_AR}`.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to give hint to CMake as others mentioned. For people who use visual studio, lib.exe is in the compiler directory. So adding the following lines should fix your problem:

```
get_filename_component(MSVC_BIN_DIR "${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER}" DIRECTORY)
find_program(LIB_EXE NAMES lib.exe PATHS "${MSVC_BIN_DIR}" NO_DEFAULT_PATH)

message (STATUS ${LIB_EXE})
```